# Remove all characters till the first letter ([a-zA-Z]) in a string

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, tr

I want to remove all characters till the first letter `[a-zA-Z]`  in a string. For example:

`#121Abc` --> `Abc`

`%Ab#c` --> `Ab#c`

`Ab#c` --> `Ab#c`

`Abc` --> `Abc`

`1Abc` --> `Abc`

`1 21Abc` --> `Abc`

`1^1 Abc` --> `Abc`

Note: All non-letters includes non-printing characters.

Is it possible with bash tools?

Comment: Where is this string stored? In a shell variable or in a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with `awk`:

```
awk 'sub(/^[^[:alpha:]]*/, "")' infile
```

with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//' infile
```

---

Note: if you had lines that there is no alphabet character in it, it will end up an empty lines in output, to skip printing those lines as well as skipping the empty lines in input, you need to use:

```
awk 'sub(/^[^[:alpha:]]*/, "") && NF' infile
awk 'sub(/^[^[:alpha:]]*/, "") && /./' infile
sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//;/./!d' infile
```

or same doing with `grep` (thanks to [@glennjackman](/users/4667))

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]].*' infile
```

Comment: or grep: `grep -o '[[:alpha:]].*' file`

Comment: @glennjackman that one  removes lines that don't contain alpha's (should go in the bottom section).

Answer (score 6):

With POSIX sh parameter expansion operators (initially from ksh), assuming the input is in a shell variable:

```
$ string='#123Abc'
$ printf '%s\n' "${string#"${string%%[[:alpha:]]*}"}"
Abc
```

Note that what `[A-Za-z]` matches is unspecified except in the C locale. In practice, it's rather random, [especially with the `bash` shell](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html).

`[[:alpha:]]` matches on all characters considered as letter (or more generally characters that are commonly part of the transcription of human language words even in non-alphabetic scripts) in the locale. To match only on ASCII English letters regardless of the locale, you'd use `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.

Answer (score 3):

Using only Bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a='#121Abc'
$ printf '%s\n' "${a/#*([!a-zA-Z])/}"
Abc
```

(and so on, setting `a` to whichever string you want to process).

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6):

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ <:!Letter>+ //;'
```

OR (more simply):

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ <:!L>+ //;'
```

Sample Input:

```
#121Abc --> Abc
%Ab#c --> Ab#c
Ab#c --> Ab#c
Abc --> Abc
1Abc --> Abc
1 21Abc --> Abc
1^1 Abc --> Abc
_!_Abc --> Abc
!Åbc --> Åbc
_Åbc --> Åbc
```

Sample Output:

```
Abc --> Abc
Ab#c --> Ab#c
Ab#c --> Ab#c
Abc --> Abc
Abc --> Abc
Abc --> Abc
Abc --> Abc
Abc --> Abc
Åbc --> Åbc
Åbc --> Åbc
```

Including this answer in case the OP has Unicode text that needs handling. Briefly, Raku's `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags are used to implement the well-known (`sed`-like) `s///` idiom.

As for character sets, Raku provides character sets based on **Unicode properties**. The Unicode letter character class is denoted using `<:Letter>`, and its negation is denoted by adding an `!` exclamation mark like so: `<:!Letter>`. There are two Unicode Letter subclasses that are useful as well, `<:Lu>` Letter-uppercase and `<:Ll>` Letter lowercase.

If you have blank lines that need removal, you can switch to the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags, like so:

```perl
raku -ne 'S/^ <:!Letter>+ //.put if .chars;'
```

There are a few other regex options...Raku also provides  **Predefined character classes** such as the `<alpha>` class, which includes *"alphabetic characters plus underscore (_)"*. It's fairly easy to remember that in Raku, `<alnum>` equals `<alpha>` plus `<digits>`. Note for character sets in this category, negation is indicated with a leading `-` minus sign:

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ <-alpha>+ //;'
```

Above handles the sample file correctly (including Unicode) except for the third-from-last line where `_!_Abc` remains unaltered, and the last line where `_Åbc` remains unaltered. To remove these leading `_` underscores the alternation code below works (although using the Unicode `<:Letter>` class at top is simpler, since that class does not contain `_` underscore):

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ [<-alpha>+ | <[_]>+]+ //;'
```

Finally, if the OP believes that Unicode characters won't be encountered, the simple character `range`(s) below work (again, with a leading `-` minus sign to indicate negation):

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ <-[A..Za..z]>+ //;'
```

Note however, the code immediately above--while simple to grasp--won't handle the last two lines of the Sample Input file properly, returning `bc` instead of the (presumably) desired `Åbc`.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

without tools, but only with `bash` features:

```
foo="#121Abc"
[[ "$foo" =~ ^[^a-zA-Z]* ]] && printf "%s\\n" "${foo:${#BASH_REMATCH}}"
```

---

`tr` to `d`elete the `c`omplement of the charset you say:

```
printf "%s\\n" "$foo" | tr -dc [a-zA-Z]
```

---

`perl` transliteration :

```
printf "%s\\n" "$foo" | perl -ple 'y/a-zA-Z//dc'
```